# Event target comes back as null when I try to read it after uploading a file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file

I'm building a resume uploader  form and I'd like to show the uploaded files name after it get's uploaded. I have an `onChange` handler for when the uploaded file is changed, but when I try to read the event's properties, specifically target as that's where I read my infor should be, it comes back as null.

This is my file input uploader:

```
        <input
          id="upload-resume"
          className="update-profile__upload"
          type="file"
          onChange={handleFileUpload}
        />
```

And this is my handler:

```
  const handleFileUpload = file => {
    console.log("This is the file");
    console.log(file);
  };
```

Comment: `event.target.file` instead of just file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access all the file properties.

```
const [filesState, setFilesState] = React.useState([]);

return (
  <>
    <input
      type="file"
      name="file-upload"
      onChange={e => {
        setFilesState(e.target.files);
      }}
    />
    <br />
    {Array.from(filesState).map((file, index) => {
      return (
        <div key={index}>
          <p>Name: {file.name}</p>
          <p>Type: {file.type}</p>
          <p>Size: {Number(file.size / 1000).toFixed(2)} KB</p>
        </div>
      );
    })}
  </>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

this works.

```
const handleFileUpload = file => {
  console.log("This is the file");
  console.log(file.target.files[0]);
};
```

refer here for more info on uploading file. [upload file](https://programmingwithmosh.com/javascript/react-file-upload-proper-server-side-nodejs-easy/)

Comment: it is always advisable to link to official docs instead of some random website.

Answer (score 0):

The [uploaded file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) is in the [files array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) of the target.

```
const handleFileUpload = file => {
  console.log("This is the file");
  // array of files with the following properties
  // name, type, lastModified , size
  console.log(file.target.files);
};
```